# handling time distinct from datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

The goal is to compare timestamp to a range of times.

The range of times were defined in the rails schema as `t.time` for postgresql database.  However the data returned upon querying the console attributes a date to the record's field...

```
start_time: "2000-01-01 08:00:00"
end_time: "2000-01-01 17:59:59"
```

Now if I want to validate whether a record `created_at: "2017-03-18 03:44:04"` is in the time range, I am also comparing the date, which is throwing the query into empty-array-land.

What rails or ruby tools can be used in this case in a database-agnostic manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def within_time_range?(start_time, end_time, time_check)
  t = time_check[11..-1]
  t >= start_time[11..-1] && t <= end_time[11..-1]
end

start_time = "2000-01-01 08:00:00"
end_time   = "2000-01-01 17:59:59"

within_time_range?(start_time, end_time, "2017-03-18 03:44:04")
  #=> false
within_time_range?(start_time, end_time, "2017-03-18 09:05:01")
  #=> true
within_time_range?(start_time, end_time, "2017-03-18 19:05:01")
  #=> false
```

Note

```
start_time[11..-1]
  #=> "08:00:00"
```

I've used `String#<=` and `String#>=`, which are obtained from [String#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) and the inclusion of the module [Comparable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Comparable.html) into the `String` class.

Comment: Elegant! And the references to the ruby classes and modules provide proper enlightenment.

Comment: Not so robust IMHO. It only works for this very specific format and ignores additional information (e.g. timezone).

Comment: @EricDuminil, one could make this more robust, but not without potential pitfalls.  `String#parse`, for example, would permit other date/time formats, but would also happily accept strings such as `"9111116cat"`: `Time.parse("9111116cat") => 9111-01-01 00:00:00 -0800`. Better, imo, to use what I have or [DateTime#strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime), and change the code if the format is to be changed. As you may surmise, I am not a fan of `parse`.

Comment: Note that the input comes from a DB. `"9111116cat"` isn't going to happen, but daylight saving time, a change of postgres to sqlite or a postgres update might break your solution. `Time#parse` is far from being perfectly robust, but it will surely correctly understand anything that comes from a DB. I'm not a fan of `Time#parse` but I like hardcoding formats even less.

Comment: It might be my ego speaking, though. I also don't like answering first with a valid answer and not getting any feedback. :)

Comment: @Eric, I know what you mean, having written many killer answers that garnered no upvotes nor, evidently, even notice. Self-satisfaction was my only reward, both that wasn't so bad.

Answer (score 1):

You could force every time object to be parsed at the same date (e.g. 1st of january 2000) :

```
require 'time'

def parse_time_not_date(string)
  time = Time.parse(string)
  Time.local(2000, 1, 1, time.hour, time.min, time.sec, time.usec)
end

start_time = parse_time_not_date("2000-01-01 08:00:00")
end_time = parse_time_not_date("2000-01-01 17:59:59")

my_time = parse_time_not_date("2017-03-18 03:44:04")
puts (start_time..end_time).cover?(my_time)
# false
puts (start_time..end_time).cover?(parse_time_not_date("2017-03-18 14:59"))
# true
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to chime in, as the discussion from the first answer was pertinent.  Cary's answer works for that case.  The question was ambivalent in terms of possible solutions: ruby or rails. And hence some potential gum ups.  What follows is another way.

With rails, there is an issue in considering time zones. Calling an object of data type `time` actually stays in UTC.  With `date_time` you are getting a string with + or - hours(or fraction thereof - yay Newfoundland!)

So, processing with rails, the [proper way to handle UTC data is to assign it the rails application time zone](http://danilenko.org/2012/7/6/rails_timezones/) with `in_time_zone`, chain to  string and then extracting.  Thus, comparisons ended up as:

```
p = Time.parse(@interruptions[0].pause.to_s[11,8])
p >= Time.parse(d_s.start_time.in_time_zone.to_s[11,8]) && p <= Time.parse(d_s.end_time.in_time_zone.to_s[11,8])
```

Note: could not get `[11..-1]` working in this context